# winapi display icon on the screen with mouseclick event

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In WINAPI, I have seen a virus which displays an icon on the x-y of the mouse whenever a mouse click event occurs (the red one which has a white X inside). How do I show an icon like that whenever I click the mouse? I know how to hook mouse clicks with setwindowshookex. Is there a function like iconshow as I have shown below.

```
HHOOK msHOOK;
//getting the icon let's say from a rc file
HICON redIcon; 

msHOOK = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, NULL, 0);

LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wPar, LPARAM lPar){
  IconShow(NULL, redIcon, xofMouse, yofMouse, 0);
  MessageBox(NULL, "Icon showed", "Cap", 0);
  return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wPar, lPar);
}

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdParam, int iCmdShow){
    HWND wnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "ClassName";
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED, "ClassName", "ss", NULL, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(wnd, RGB(255, 255, 0), 20, LWA_COLORKEY);
    ShowWindow(wnd, SW_SHOW);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            //stuff here
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can load your image as an `HCURSOR` instead of an `HICON`, then look at the Win32 API [`SetCursor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393.aspx) function.

Comment: I have updated @RemyLebeau

Comment: If you use a window at all, you can't use standard `BUTTON` for this. You need a custom window class (see `RegisterClass()`) with a custom window procedure that handles `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` paint messages. Unless you use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to assign a bitmap as the window's entire display, then you don't need to handle those messages.

Comment: Thanks, you are saying I should use WNDCLASSEX and put the classname to the second parameter? also I did not use WS_CAPTION, or neither WS_BORDER. This is all I have done, or wait i will update it.

Comment: damn, this is hard, also the program appears on taskbar, I just wanted a simple small img to be appeared, but i love it because i learn :) @RemyLebeau

Comment: Creating custom window is hard. If you don't understand the basics of how windows work, you are not going to succeed at this.  There is TONS of information on MSDN about this. Also, you can use the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style to get rid of the taskbar button.

Comment: thanks, I got rid of it. I want to be better at this so I will try. my only help is msdn and you guys. also I am going correctly now, right? the window does not appear at this moment when I removed `TEXT("button")` it should be appearing when I put in function inside `WM_PAINT` I suppose? @RemyLebeau

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for tutorials on how to do things.  There are plenty of online tutorials for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create your own always-on-top window to display the cursor.

It probably needs to be a [layered window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) so you can use [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx) and a 32-bit RGBA bitmap to get every cursor looking correct.

If you are only using a specific cursor you control, and it does not have an alpha channel, you can save yourself some work by painting the image as-is onto your window in a `WM_ERASEBKGND` or `WM_PAINT` message handler, and then use [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes(..., LWA_COLORKEY, ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the window's transparency color.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am sorry I got this far, I am really noob at this. This only shows an empty button with a title bar, i am not worried about it being at the top for the moment. how do i make it an icon/cursor, and how do i put the icon there. can you please make some edits? also, thank you very much.

Comment: @turmuka You have to register a window class and paint the cursor in [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162487(v=vs.85).aspx) and paint the background with your LWA_COLORKEY color.

Comment: I see, how do i get rid of the title bar? @Ander

Comment: @turmuka: remove the window's `WS_CAPTION` style. You will probably want to remove the `WS_BORDER` style, too.

Comment: @Anders how do i trigger click events inside `WM_PAINT` ?

Comment: You don't. Your mouse hook will know when the mouse is clicked. When it is clicked you save that state somewhere and call InvalidateRect on your window and in WM_PAINT you use your saved state to decide what to paint.